# How to add text & call to action button to featured image on homepage?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I do not have coding experience only what I've learned to be able to modify my WP themes.  I am stuck on the following issue.  I'd like to add text and a call to action button to the featured image on my static homepage.

I'm fine using the page title as the text but I need to be able to add the call to action button button below the text.

Is this achievable by simply adding code to my custom CSS and/or one of the php files?  If yes, please let me know what code I could use.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or feedback.

Comment: I could not add my site's URL in the initial question.  This is my site, if it will be helpful: http://go2l.ink/1jhA

Answer (score 1):

If your theme allow you to edit the text displayed on your home page, when you just need to add a a link.

A click to call link is a simple HTML link, except that the value of the `href` attribute needs to refer to the "tel" protocol:

```
<a href="tel:XXXXXXXXXXXXX">Call Us</a>
```

Where "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" is your phone number.

If you only use the graphic interface, simply write "Call Us", highlight it and click on the button to add a link, and put "tel:XXXXXXXXXX" as the url.

Comment: This has been resolved.  A coder on Fiverr, created custom css that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late to answer. But there are two different methods for solving your issue.

**1. Manual Method** - You can manually add the call to action button to
    your WordPress website by using these codes:

```
    <!--This link will work on Android and iPhone. It will be visible to desktop users but will result in an error when clicked
-->

    <a href="tel:+15555551212">+1 (555) 555-1212</a> 

    <a href="tel:15555551212">Call Me</a>
```

**2. Plugin Method** - 
    You can use a plugin, like [Call Now Button](https://wordpress.org/plugins/call-now-button/), to add the call to action button. It offers you several useful customization features. You can find the detailed steps for using it [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-click-to-call-button-to-your-wordpress-website/).

Answer (score 0):

To  include a click to call button on the image you can use the following code

```
<a href="tel:+1234567890"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
```

or for a text button use

```
<a href="tel:+1234567890">+123456789</a>
```